# Create users form SharePoint

Tags: 2007, security, user, login

In SharePoint, can you create users directly from a teamsite? i.e the users are not local computer users or Active directory users, but they are created and managed from SharePoint. This means that there would be a screen in SharePoint where an Admin would need to create a user account, enter password etc. 
Is this provided in SharePoint? I would be using SharePoint 2007.

Comment: Not OOTB it isn't

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at FBA (Forms Based Authentication) [here](http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/) and [here](https://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/) which is SQL authentification, and can be managed from the site with the FBA pack

Comment: authentication* (I can't edit my comment)